# Laravel data monthly count

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display how many records were inserted every month, today is Feb 1, it should be Zero but it shows 180?

[image]

```
Card::make(
  'Incidents this month',
  IncidentReport::where('created_at', '>', now()->subDays(30))->count(),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) and `Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()` and `Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()`

```
IncidentReport::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])->count();
```

The issue is you are subtracting days from today's day.

```
now()->subDays(30)
```

This will return 01-Jan-2023

Ref: [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)